# Reading .mat file using C: how to read cell-structure properly

Tags: c, matlab

I am basically attempting to translate Matlab code in C code. This is the extension of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587571/reading-mat-file-from-c-can-read-variable-but-cannot-return-properly).

In Matlab, I have used **`cell-structures`** which holds **`matrices (double) of variable sizes`**. Here is a toy example of what my *.mat file is **`supposed to store`**:

**Matlab Code:**

```
A = [[1 2 3]; [5 7 1]; [3 5 9]];
B = [[2 4];[5 7]];
Creator = 'DKumar';

nFilters = 2;

Filters{1} = [[-1.0 -1.0 -1.0]; [-1.0 8 -1.0]; [-1.0 -1.0 -1.0]];
Filters{2} = 2.0*[[-1.0 -1.0]; [-1.0 8]; [-1.0 -1.0]];

cd('/home/dkumar/CPP_ExampleCodes_DKU/Read_mat_File');
save('Test_FILE.mat', 'A', 'B', 'Creator', 'nFilters', 'Filters');
```

**C-code:** The function **`"matread_Matrix" reads matrices stored in *.mat properly`**. It's the function **`"matread_Cell"`**, which is supposed to read cell-structure, is **`not working`**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/include/mat.h"

mxArray *arr;
mxArray *C_CELL;
/* declare  a 2 x 1 array of pointers to access the cell array in C */
mxArray *cellArray[2];

struct stDoubleMat{
   double* pValueInField;
   int nRows, nCols;
};

void matread_Matrix(const char *file, const char *FieldName2Read, struct stDoubleMat* poDoubleMat_LOC)
{
    printf("Reading file %s...\n\n", file);

    //Open file to get directory
    MATFile* pmat = matOpen(file, "r");

    if (pmat == NULL) {
      printf("Error opening file %s\n", file);
      return;
    }

    // extract the specified variable
    arr = matGetVariable(pmat, FieldName2Read);

    double *pr;
    if (arr != NULL && !mxIsEmpty(arr)) {
        // copy data
        mwSize num = mxGetNumberOfElements(arr);

        pr = mxGetPr(arr);

        if (pr != NULL) {
        poDoubleMat_LOC->pValueInField = pr;
            poDoubleMat_LOC->nRows  = mxGetM(arr);
            poDoubleMat_LOC->nCols  = mxGetN(arr);
        }
    printf("matread_Matrix \n") ;
        printf( "oDoubleMat_LOC.nRows %i ; oDoubleMat_LOC.nCols %i \n", poDoubleMat_LOC->nRows , poDoubleMat_LOC->nCols);

    }else{
        printf("nothing to read \n") ;
    }


    // close the file
    matClose(pmat);

    return;
}

void matread_Cell(const char *file, const char *FieldName2Read, int CellIndex)
{
    printf("Reading file %s...\n\n", file);

    //Open file to get directory
    MATFile* pmat = matOpen(file, "r");

    if (pmat == NULL) {
      printf("Error opening file %s\n", file);
      return;
    }

    // extract the specified variable
    C_CELL = matGetVariable(pmat, FieldName2Read);
    cellArray[CellIndex] = mxGetCell(C_CELL, CellIndex);

    double* p2 = (double*)cellArray[CellIndex];
    int nRows  = mxGetM(cellArray[CellIndex]);
    int nCols  = mxGetN(cellArray[CellIndex]);

    printf(" From inside matread_Cell : nRows %i and nCols %i \n", nRows, nCols);

    int i2;
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < nRows*nCols; i2++)
    {
    printf(" copied value : %f \n", *p2);
    p2 = p2 +1;
    }

    // close the file
    matClose(pmat);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *FileName = "/home/dkumar/CPP_ExampleCodes_DKU/Read_mat_File/Test_FILE.mat";
    const char *FieldName2Read = "A";

    struct stDoubleMat oDoubleMat; 
    matread_Matrix(FileName, FieldName2Read, &oDoubleMat);
    double* v = oDoubleMat.pValueInField;


    printf("From main \n");
    printf( "oDoubleMat.nRows %i ; oDoubleMat.nCols %i \n", oDoubleMat.nRows , oDoubleMat.nCols);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < oDoubleMat.nCols*oDoubleMat.nRows; i++)
    {
        printf(" copied value : %f \n", *v);
        v = v +1;
    }

    // Reading the structure
    const char *FieldName2Read2 = "Filters";
    matread_Cell(FileName, FieldName2Read2, 0);
    matread_Cell(FileName, FieldName2Read2, 1);


    // cleanup the mex-array
    mxDestroyArray(arr);
    mxDestroyArray(C_CELL);
    /* How to delete mxArray of pointer : should this be a array of pointers */
    //mxDestroyArray(cellArray[0]);
    //mxDestroyArray(cellArray[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ gcc -g -o Test Read_MatFile_DKU_2.c -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/include -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/bin/glnxa64 -lmat -lmx

$ ./Test 
Reading file /home/dkumar/CPP_ExampleCodes_DKU/Read_mat_File/Test_FILE.mat...

matread_Matrix 
oDoubleMat_LOC.nRows 3 ; oDoubleMat_LOC.nCols 3 
From main 
oDoubleMat.nRows 3 ; oDoubleMat.nCols 3 
 copied value : 1.000000 
 copied value : 5.000000 
 copied value : 3.000000 
 copied value : 2.000000 
 copied value : 7.000000 
 copied value : 5.000000 
 copied value : 3.000000 
 copied value : 1.000000 
 copied value : 9.000000 
Reading file /home/dkumar/CPP_ExampleCodes_DKU/Read_mat_File/Test_FILE.mat...

 From inside matread_Cell : nRows 3 and nCols 3 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
Reading file /home/dkumar/CPP_ExampleCodes_DKU/Read_mat_File/Test_FILE.mat...

 From inside matread_Cell : nRows 3 and nCols 2 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000 
 copied value : 0.000000
```

Also, I could not read this field properly as well: Creator = 'DKumar';

UPDATE:

Based on suggestion of @Sherwin

My C-code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2011b/extern/include/mat.h"

mxArray *arr;
mxArray *C_CELL;
/* declare  a 2 x 1 array of pointers to access the cell array in C */
mxArray *cellArray[2];

struct stDoubleMat{
   double* pValueInField;
   int nRows, nCols;
};


void matread_Matrix(MATFile* pmat , const char *FieldName2Read, struct stDoubleMat* poDoubleMat_LOC)
{
    // extract the specified variable
    arr = matGetVariable(pmat, FieldName2Read);

    double *pr;
    if (arr != NULL && !mxIsEmpty(arr)) {
        // copy data
        mwSize num = mxGetNumberOfElements(arr);

        pr = mxGetPr(arr);

        if (pr != NULL) {
        poDoubleMat_LOC->pValueInField = pr;
            poDoubleMat_LOC->nRows  = mxGetM(arr);
            poDoubleMat_LOC->nCols  = mxGetN(arr);
        }
    printf("matread_Matrix \n") ;
        printf( "oDoubleMat_LOC.nRows %i ; oDoubleMat_LOC.nCols %i \n", poDoubleMat_LOC->nRows , poDoubleMat_LOC->nCols);

    }else{
        printf("nothing to read \n") ;
    }
    return;
}

void matread_String(MATFile* pmat , const char *FieldName2Read)
{
    // extract the specified variable
    arr = matGetVariable(pmat, FieldName2Read);

    double *pr;
    if (arr != NULL && !mxIsEmpty(arr)) {
        // copy data
        mwSize num = mxGetNumberOfElements(arr);
        pr = mxGetPr(arr);

        if (pr != NULL) {
            char *p2 = (char*) pr; 

            // Printing and checking
        int i2;
        for (i2 = 0; i2 < num; i2++)
        {
        printf(" copied value : %s \n", p2);
        p2 = p2 +1;
        }

    }

    }else{
            printf("nothing to read \n") ;
    }
    return;
}

void matread_Cell(MATFile* pmat , const char *FieldName2Read, int CellIndex)
{

    // extract the specified variable
    C_CELL = matGetVariable(pmat, FieldName2Read);
    cellArray[CellIndex] = mxGetCell(C_CELL, CellIndex);

    double *p2 = (double*) mxGetPr(cellArray[CellIndex]); 
    int nRows  = mxGetM(cellArray[CellIndex]);
    int nCols  = mxGetN(cellArray[CellIndex]);

    printf(" From inside matread_Cell : nRows %i and nCols %i \n", nRows, nCols);

    int i2;
    for (i2 = 0; i2 < nRows*nCols; i2++)
    {
    printf(" copied value : %f \n", *p2);
    p2 = p2 +1;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *FileName = "/home/dkumar/CPP_ExampleCodes_DKU/Read_mat_File/Test_FILE.mat";
    const char *FieldName2Read = "A";

    //Open file to get directory
    printf("Reading file %s...\n\n", FileName);
    MATFile* pmat = matOpen(FileName, "r");

    if (pmat == NULL) {
      printf("Error opening file %s\n", FileName);
      return;
    }

    struct stDoubleMat oDoubleMat; 
    matread_Matrix(pmat, FieldName2Read, &oDoubleMat);
    double* v = oDoubleMat.pValueInField;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < oDoubleMat.nCols*oDoubleMat.nRows; i++)
    {
        printf(" copied value : %f \n", *v);
        v = v +1;
    }

    // Reading the structure
    const char *FieldName2Read2 = "Filters";
    matread_Cell(pmat, FieldName2Read2, 0);
    matread_Cell(pmat, FieldName2Read2, 1);

    // Reading the string
    const char *FieldName2Read3 = "Creator";
    matread_String(pmat, FieldName2Read3);

    // cleanup the mex-array
    mxDestroyArray(arr);
    mxDestroyArray(C_CELL);

    /* How to delete mxArray of pointer : should this be a array of pointers */
    //mxDestroyArray(cellArray[0]);
    //mxDestroyArray(cellArray[1]);


    // close the file
    matClose(pmat);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
oDoubleMat.nRows 3 ; oDoubleMat.nCols 3 
 copied value : 1.000000 
 copied value : 5.000000 
 copied value : 3.000000 
 copied value : 2.000000 
 copied value : 7.000000 
 copied value : 5.000000 
 copied value : 3.000000 
 copied value : 1.000000 
 copied value : 9.000000 
 From inside matread_Cell : nRows 3 and nCols 3 
 copied value : -1.000000 
 copied value : -1.000000 
 copied value : -1.000000 
 copied value : -1.000000 
 copied value : 8.000000 
 copied value : -1.000000 
 copied value : -1.000000 
 copied value : -1.000000 
 copied value : -1.000000 
 From inside matread_Cell : nRows 3 and nCols 2 
 copied value : -2.000000 
 copied value : -2.000000 
 copied value : -2.000000 
 copied value : -2.000000 
 copied value : 16.000000 
 copied value : -2.000000 
 copied value : D 
 copied value :  
 copied value : K 
 copied value :  
 copied value : u 
 copied value :  
 copied value :
```

Problem: 1) String value stored in creator is not properly displayed.

2) How to delete cellArray[2])?

Comment: why are you saving the data in `MAT` format if you read it outside of Matlab? why not export the data (in Matlab) to, say, hdf5 and use existing tools for reading hdf5 binary data?

Comment: I have never used the hdf5 format before and I do not know if it can store and access cell structures.

Comment: Matlab saves its MAT files in hdf5 format (for version 7.3 and on, AFAIK). So, in principle it can do whatever you need. You'll have to get your hands dirty and learn how to interface to hdf5, but considering the fact that you are going through the same (painful) process with MAT format, I think you'll be better off learning a more versatile tool (HDF5) instead of focusing on the very restricted MAT... But this is just my opinion.

Comment: Look at [hdf5 web page](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/)  for help and tutorials

Comment: That may not be an optimum solution for me. I mostly code in Matlab and there is one single assignment where I need to speed up my data processing significantly. Fortunately, someone has already a solver written in  C-code for which he claims to be atleast 10 times faster. So, I need some quick interfacing between Matlab and C to check his claim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out with a slight change, your code works:

In the function "`void matread_Cell`" replace the line `double* p2 = (double*)cellArray[CellIndex];` with:

```
p2 = (double*) mxGetPr(cellArray[CellIndex]);
```

I checked it out. It does the work.

Also to read the creator field, a similar code to `mtread_matrix` should work, just the type is `char*` instead of `double*` (I didn't check this one though. let me know if it doesn't work).

**update:** you can use the following code to read strings. (Reference: [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetstring.html))

```
void matread_string(const char *file, const char *FieldName2Read, char *pr, mwSize *len)
{
    printf("Reading file %s...\n\n", file);

    //Open file to get directory
    MATFile* pmat = matOpen(file, "r");

    if (pmat == NULL) {
      printf("Error opening file %s\n", file);
      return;
    }

    // extract the specified variable
    arr = matGetVariable(pmat, FieldName2Read);

    if (arr != NULL && !mxIsEmpty(arr)) {
        // copy data
        mwSize num = mxGetNumberOfElements(arr);

        //int mxGetString(const mxArray *pm, char *str, mwSize strlen);
        int res= mxGetString(arr, pr, num+1); //strlen should be len+1. c.f. reference.
        if(res==0)
            printf("success!\n");
        else
            printf("failed.\n");


        if ( pr == NULL){
            printf("null pointer.\n");
        }   
        printf("matread_string \n") ;
        printf( "len: %i \n", (int)num);

        *len=num; 

    }else{
        printf("nothing to read \n") ;
    }
    // close the file
    matClose(pmat);

    return;
}
```

In the `main` you can use it like:

```
 const char *FieldName2Read3 = "Creator";
    char pr[20];
    mwSize len;
    matread_string(FileName, FieldName2Read3, pr, &len);

    //int i;
    printf(" copied value: %s \n",pr);
    for (i = 0; (mwSize) i <  len; i++)
    {
        printf(" copied value : %c \n", pr[i]);
    }
```

Regarding deallocating cellArray, I get the error: "pointer being freed was not allocated", so I don't think you need to free that. Another useful command for freeing dynamic memory is : `void mxFree(void *ptr);`

Regarding the `mexPrintf` function I am actually able to use it. I just get a warning `implicit declaration of function 'mexPrintf' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`, since I am compiling via gcc rather than mex. If you are using gcc, you probably need to include the proper libraries to recognize that function. You might find [this](http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=924) useful, as it worked for me.

Comment: I updated my code based on your suggestion and I can read CellArray, still can not read the string. Also, i do not know how to delete cellArray[2]). Also, I would have preferred to use mexPrintf. But, I am getting an error: undefined reference to `mexPrintf'.
 Any guess about that??